# Access restriction in java after Java9

Tags: java, java-9, access-modifiers, java-module

With the introduction of modules in Java 9, do the access restrictions based on access modifiers for classes have any real relevance. Module definition can ultimately control what is exposed outside and that is what is really important for a utility or library.

Though class access modifiers provide a different level of control, but is that really required or is it more of a legacy feature that java has to carry along.

Comment: Within a [tag:java-module] the package level abstraction of classes would still remain the same as it exists before that.

Comment: yes, the package level access restriction will still remain in the language. But are they really useful for real life applications.